# Why is Phoenix LiveView Function `push_event` undefined?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I want to send an Event from liveView server to the Client, with this funtion:

```
  def handle_event("test", _, socket) do
    {:noreply, push_event(socket, "testEvent", %{coins: 23, user: "user"})}
  end
```

This is explained very similar in the docs of liveview.
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/js-interop.html
But i get this error message:

```
(CompileError) undefined function push_event/3

Stacktrace:
  │ (elixir 1.10.4) src/elixir_locals.erl:114: anonymous fn/3 in :elixir_locals.ensure_no_undefined_local/3
  │ (stdlib 3.8) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

have i missed some inmport? or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the Problem was my version of live view.
I had to upgrade:

```
{:phoenix_live_view, "~> 0.13.0"},
```

to:

```
{:phoenix_live_view, "~> 0.14.4"},
```

Comment: yes, `push_event` was added with version 0.14 if I remember correctly